# When editing a R shiny datatable cell the font color of the value is white. How to change the font color in the editable box to black

Tags: r, shiny, colors, edit, dt

I am editing datatable cells. When I click on the cell to edit the values, I don't see the value as the font color is white same as the background of the edit box. Here is a screenshot to show the edit box how it is when clicked:

[image]

Here is my script:

```
 output$impelastab = DT::renderDataTable( {
                print("output table")
               print( names(df_merge))
                datatable(   x$df3 , 
                          selection = 'none', editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = c(0,1)), color = 'black'),  style = "bootstrap" ,
                          rownames = FALSE,
                          options = list( 
                            searching = TRUE,
                            autoWidth = FALSE,
                            columnDefs = list(
                              list(width = '15px', targets = c(0)),
                              list(width = '100px', targets = c(1)),
                              list(width = '60px', targets = c(2))
                            ),
                            paging = TRUE,
                          lengthChange = FALSE,
                          scrollX = '100%',
                          scrollY = '500px',
                          scrollCollapse = TRUE,
                          dom = 'Bfrtip',
                          initComplete = JS(
                            "function(settings, json) {",
                            "$('th', this.api().table().header()).css('color', 'white');",
                            "}"
                          )
                          )
                          ) %>%
                  DT::formatStyle(
                    names(df_merge),
                    color = "white",
                    # fontWeight = "bold",
                    backgroundColor = "transparent",
                    fontStyle = "normal",
                    fontSize = "inherit"
                  ) 
              })
```

How to change the font color of the value in the box when the cell is in edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar and reverted back to the old datatables styling using the following code.

```
/* Update to default DT row and text selected color */
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dt-row-selected', '#a6b4cd');
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dt-row-selected-text', '#333');
```

You can either put it in a `.js` script and source it in the ui (recommended) or add it directly in the ui like so.

```
# sourcing
ui <- fluidPage(
  withTags(
    header(script(src = 'js/script.js'))
  ),
 DTOutput('table')
)

# inline
ui <- fluidPage(
  withTags(
    header(
      script(HTML(
       "document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dt-row-selected', '#a6b4cd');
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--dt-row-selected-text', '#333');"
       ))  
    )
  ),
 DTOutput('table')
)
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: it does not work. When I click on the cell to be edited still the box is white completely and the font color is white in the box. This is occuring due to the fact that I changed the font color of the datatable to white.

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you include any additional code that your current example is missing to reproduce your issue? By default, the JS datatables library styles "selected" text as white. My answer reverts that to the previous styling which is `#333`.

Comment: yeah in the exampe it works but for some reason in my script it does not work. Its a huge project with many modules. I am implementing this in one module.

Comment: Hmm, I would suggest adding the js code in a script and sourcing it in your main UI section. Or if you can edit your post to clearly display the error I can assist as well. Without that it's tough to debug.

Comment: i have edit my script to show the output datatable. When I use your javascript in the main js script it does not work. It stays the same., white font white background.

Comment: I see, that's cause you're overriding it in your datatable call. I would remove references to change the text white.

Comment: I don't understand which references? the formatstyle?

Comment: yep `color = 'white'` and `backgroundColor = 'transparent'` and possibly your initComplete call. Although that appears to only affect `<th>` so it may not be necessary.

Comment: In fact I am using a black background then using transparent background on the datatable.  Then I am putting the font to white. So I will need to be able to edit the cell with either the font appear black in the white edit box or the background of the edit box is changed to black.

Comment: I got the best solution. Just add .table.dataTable input{
  color: black !important;
} to the css file